# Python openpyxl _images get data?

Tags: python, image, copy, openpyxl

My python version is     3.11
openpyxl                 3.1.2

```
path = r"D:\input"
wb = op.load_workbook(path + "/test.xlsx")
ws = wb.active 

data1 = ws["B2"].value
img_obj = ws._images[0]

img_data = img_obj.image # error
```

I'm trying to get image data but I'm getting this error;

```
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'image'
```

So I tried changing it to the property of img_obj.img_data, but the result was the same.

```
img_data = img_obj.image_data # error
```

How can I access my image data?
I'd like to insert image into my cell like this :

```
ws.add_image(img_obj, "D6")
```

There is no problem with files outside the Excel file,
and this problem occurs when I try to copy the image inside the Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do what it looks like you want.
Basically copy and existing image in the sheet to another location

The only trouble is I tried it with the latest openpyxl version `3.1.2` and found that `image_loader.get(image_loc)` causes an issue with the workbook and if don't reload the workbook and sheet again I get an error and  corrupted workbook. When they are reloaded as shown the file saves correctly.
The code works on the original version I wrote this for which is `3.0.9` without having to reload the workbook/worksheet so maybe its an bug with the latest release.

```
import openpyxl as op
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
from openpyxl_image_loader import SheetImageLoader


path = r"D:\input"
wb = op.load_workbook(path + "/test.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

image_loc = 'A2' # Location of the original image in the sheet
image_loader = SheetImageLoader(ws)

### This loop can be used to find the image location if not known
# for image_loc in image_loader._images:
#     print(image_loc)
#     image_list_loc = image_loc

### load image from image location
### When this line is run on openpyxl 3.1.2 need to reload the workbook/sheet
image = Image(image_loader.get(image_loc))

### Reload the workbook and sheet
wb = op.load_workbook("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

### Add the image to new location
ws.add_image(image, 'D6')

### Save workbook
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Image at cell "A2" copied to cell "D6"
[image: Example]